# Tests failing when using ClientInterceptor to add headers to the stub

Tags: grpc-java, kotest, grpc-kotlin

In the following code `MetadataUtils.attachHeaders` is deprecated (I'm using grpc 1.45.1):

```kotlin
    "request without bearer token should fail" {
        val channel: ManagedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(address, port)
            .usePlaintext()
            .build()
        var stub = RuleAPIGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)

        val metadata = Metadata()
        metadata.put(Metadata.Key.of("Authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), "no token ")
        stub = MetadataUtils.attachHeaders(stub, metadata)

        val exception = shouldThrow<StatusRuntimeException> {
            stub.getRule(
                RuleApiProto.GetRuleRequest.newBuilder().build()
            )
        }

        exception.status.code.name shouldBe Code.UNAUTHENTICATED.name
        exception.status.description shouldBe Errors.MISSING_BEARER_TOKEN.name

        channel.shutdown()
    }
```

I tried to replace it with:

```kotlin
stub.withInterceptors(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(metadata))
```

But then tests are failing, because of missing AUTH header.
When I add the interceptor to the channel:

```kotlin
.intercept(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(metadata))
```

then everything works fine.

And ideas why it doesn't work for the stub?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear from your description if you are already doing this, but you'll need to use the returned value of the stub from `withInterceptors()` like this:

```
stub 
  = stub.withInterceptors(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(metadata));

stub.getRule(...)...
```

Comment: In the code snippet I added to my question there is ```stub.getRule(```

Comment: My point was that `stub.withInterceptors` returns a new value which you need to assign to the variable `stub` and use that in making the call. From your description it is not clear if you are assigning the new value back to `stub`. I can see that you are doing `stub.getRule()` and there is no issue with that.